# Distance between unbounded closed convex subsets of Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are nonempty closed convex subsets of the Hilbert space $H$.

**Case I:** If $A$ or $B$ is bounded, I can prove that there exist $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that
$$d(A,B) = d(a,b),$$
where
$d(A,B) := \inf\{d(x,y)\mid x\in A,\, y\in B\}$.

**Case II:** If both $A$ and $B$ are unbounded and assume $\lim_{\|x\|,\|y\|\to\infty} d(x,y) = \infty$, how to prove the same result as in Case I?

**The proof of Case I:**

Without loss of generality, we can assume that $A$ is bounded. For any $n\geq 1$, there exists some $x_n\in A$ such that
$$d(x_n, B) < d(A, B) + \frac1n.$$
Since $(x_n)$ is bounded, there exists some $a\in A$ such that $x_n\rightharpoonup a$ in the weak topology of $H$, i.e.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \langle x_n, y\rangle = \langle a, y\rangle\quad \forall y\in H.$$

Since
$$\begin{align}
  \|x_n - P_B(x_n)\|^2
  & = \|x_n-a+a-P_B(a)+P_B(a)-P_B(x_n)\|^2 \\
  & = \|a-P_B(a)\|^2 + \|x_n-a+P_B(a)-P_B(x_n)\|^2 \\
  & \quad + 2\mathrm{Re}\langle a-P_B(a), x_n-a\rangle + 2\mathrm{Re}\langle a-P_B(a), P_B(a)-P_B(x_n)\rangle \\
  & \geq \|a-P_B(a)\|^2 + 2\mathrm{Re}\langle a-P_B(a), x_n-a\rangle.
\end{align}$$
We have
\begin{align*}
    (d(A,B))^2
    & \leq \|a-P_B(a)\|^2\leq\|x_n-P_B(x_n)\|^2 - 2\mathrm{Re}\langle a-P_B(a),x_n-a\rangle\\
    & < \biggl(d(A,B)+\frac{1}{n}\biggr)^2 - 2\mathrm{Re}\langle a-P_B(a),x_n-a\rangle \\
    & \quad \to (d(A,B))^2 \qquad \text{as } n\to\infty.
  \end{align*}

It follows that $d(a,b) = d(A,B)$ where $b = P_B(a)$.

Comment: There is a restricted condition $\lim_{\|x\|,\|y\|\to\infty} d(x,y) = \infty$. @AnneBauval

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that case II follows from case I: Let $K[x,r]$ denote the closed ball in $H$ with center $x$ and radius $r$. Under the assumptions of case II let $\alpha:= \inf \{\|x-y\| \mid x \in A, y \in B\}$. Choose $M:= \alpha +1$. By assumption there is some $r_1 >  0$ such that
$$
\forall x \in A, ~ \forall y \in B: ~ (\|x\|\ge r_1 \wedge \|y\|\ge r_1 ~ \Rightarrow ~ \|x-y\| \ge M).
$$
Set $A_0:=A \cap K[0,r_2]$ and $B_0:= B\cap K[0,r_2]$ with
$r_2:= r_1 + M$.
Let $x \in A,y \in B$ such that $x \in A\setminus A_0$ **or** $y \in B\setminus B_0$.
If $\|x\|,\|y\| \ge r_1$ then $\|x-y\| \ge M$. If $\|x\| < r_1$ then $x \in A_0$ (since $r_2 > r_1$), hence $y \notin B_0$, so $\|y\| > r_2$. Therefore
$$
\|x-y\| \ge \|y\|-\|x\| > r_2-r_1 = M.
$$
The same way $\|y\| < r_1$ implies $\|x-y\| > M$. Thus
$$
\alpha= \inf \{\|x-y\| \mid x \in A, y \in B\} = \inf \{\|x-y\| \mid x \in A_0, y \in B_0\}.
$$
Now $A_0,B_0$ are bounded, nonempty, closed and convex. From case I you get some $a \in A_0$ and $b \in B_0$ with $\|a-b\|= \alpha$.

Comment: Rigorous proof! Thank you!@Gerd

Comment: (+1) omg how didn' I think of $r_2:=r_1+M$?